# E_RUNTIME_SYSTEM_ERROR on Azure Data Lake Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am doing some benchmark on Azure Data Lake Analytics. After running a query during an execution phase Combine_partition, I got error:

ERROR
E_RUNTIME_SYSTEM_ERROR
MESSAGE
A system error has been reported [VirtualAlloc returned 0]

It looks like out of memory exceptions. Any idea?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoRaX.png)

Comment: There will be a larger error report with more detail on the Errors tab of the main job result / report.  Can you get that?  Also what code are you running?  Please post it.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like your join may have received too much data and ran out of the 6GB memory that a vertex get.

The suggestion is to distribute the data or operation better by either having a better distribution strategy for that join (e.g., avoiding data skew where one bucket is too large), use a different operation that provides you with better scale, or add some data hints that "lures" the optimizer to make better partitioning decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved.

Vertex ran out of the memory, so I changed my query, eliminating GROUP BY using WINDOWING functions on same data and partitions.

Tnx for help.

Comment: It would be great if you shared some of your old code and your new code so people who have the same error can understand how you solved it.  You can simplify it a bit, or change names so it's not exactly like your production code, but that would be useful for people having the same error and landing at this page.